# Хранимая процедура для подсчета факториала числа

Tags: sql-server

Уважаемые форумчане и знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста, как написать хранимую процедуру в mssql server, подсчитывающую факториал числа. (5! = 1*2*3*4*5 = 120) (0! = 1) (факториала отрицательного числа не существует).
Наработки прикрепил, не понято последнее (0! = 1) (факториала отрицательного числа не существует), подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает решение данной задачи. Заранее огромная благодарность.

```
DECLARE @X INT, @Cnt INT
SET NoCount ON
SET @X=1
SET @Cnt=1
While (@Cnt<=5)
BEGIN
SELECT @X=@X*@Cnt
SELECT @Cnt=@Cnt+1
END
SET NoCount OFF
SELECT RESULT=@X
```

Comment: так вы википедию хотя бы откройте и прочитайте определение факториала для начала

Comment: Открывал, читал! Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: тогда что вам не понятно с  существованием факториала отрицательных чисел и значением факториала нуля?